# Error in installing google assistant on windows 10

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to install gogle-assistant-sdk on Windows 10, and I'm getting a weird error which I can't understand.

After installing python for all users and setting ENV variables when i run this command -

```
py -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]
```

I got following error -

```
Command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import 
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ramji\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip- 
install-p29c8ggl\\grpcio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
record-7znlf3rz\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
install-p29c8ggl\grpcio\
```

Detailed output -

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p29c8ggl\grpcio\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 292, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 199, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 844, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 493, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p29c8ggl\grpcio\setup.py", line 348, in <module>
    cmdclass=COMMAND_CLASS,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 78, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p29c8ggl\grpcio\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 295, in build_extensions
    support.diagnose_build_ext_error(self, error, formatted_exception)
  File "C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p29c8ggl\grpcio\src\python\grpcio\support.py", line 109, in diagnose_build_ext_error
    "backtrace).\n\n{}".format(formatted))
commands.CommandError:

We could not diagnose your build failure. If you are unable to proceed, please file an issue at http://www.github.com/grpc/grpc with `[Python install]` in the title; please attach the whole log (including everything that may have appeared above the Python backtrace).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 490, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p29c8ggl\grpcio\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 292, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 199, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 844, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 493, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools


----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import 
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ramji\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip- 
install-p29c8ggl\\grpcio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
record-7znlf3rz\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ramji\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
`enter code here`install-p29c8ggl\grpcio\
```

I even tried executing this commmand on another windows 10 machine And i got the same result.

Does anyone know what is the problem and solution for it?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like build tools are required in order to compile certain dependencies:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: This link is dead and has been for a few months. The page was last active in May 2018. The WaybackEngine provides a caches version here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180519124754/http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the stand alone build tools for Microsoft Visual C++ no longer exist. Instead Microsoft prefer you install their 6GB visual studio, which many old links direct to. Many of us realize that this requirement is despotic and want the stand alone installer back.

The following location seems to host the build tools for VS2015. However, it told me they are going to be between 3gb and 6gb in size:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

The size does not make any sense for just the C++ build tools. However, I am told this is correct. It seems in true MS fashion it ships with a lot of extra baggage most of use will not even care about.